# Ruby Gem command line tool

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am trying to build a command line [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) [gem](/questions/tagged/gem). I am using bundler to create the gem and install the gem locally. It generated the needed directories. I also was able to test that if I require my *Gem* I can use methods inside of it. I am trying to get the command line piece working now and can't seem to get it working. I want to be able to do something like

```
gemname command
```

Similar to how [rspec](/questions/tagged/rspec) works:

```
rspec test/whatever.rb
```

Any help on how to be able to execute through the command line would be great.

Comment: You have to implement the binary/command line tool yourself. See https://github.com/jimweirich/rake/tree/master/bin for an example

Comment: Are you able to explain a little more? So I create that executable and then run bundle install and it should just work? Also when it does Rake.application.run is that specific to the rake command? Do I need it in my Gem? When I run mygem mycommand it just says command not found mygem

Answer (score 3):

In order to declared the executables you have to just make a proper line in your  **yourgem.gemspec**:

```
`git ls-files -- bin/*`.split("\n").map{ |f| File.basename(f) }
```

This line, along with an other useful line is generated by `bundle gem yourgem` command. Just execute it, and then fix the **yourgem.gemspec** according your needs. Put executables into **bin/** folder of your gem, and all libraries, including the version, into **lib/** folder.

The next step is to use the binary. When you are installing the [gem](/questions/tagged/gem) into a system, the binary folder is automatically included into binary search path. So your gem is avaiable to execute from anywere. But when your gem isn't installed you are still able to simelate the case with a [bundler](/questions/tagged/bundler)'s exec as follows:

```
 bundle exec bin/your_exec
```

It picks the require librarires up from **lib/** folder, and the executable will work properly.

To make sure that the executable will work, build the gem with `gem build yourgem.gemspec`, then install it with `gem install yourgem.gem`, and try.

Comment: Okay so this seems to work when I use bundle exec bin/my_exec. So when I publish this your saying the user will be able to just run mygemname mycommand? Can I test this out locally before publishing it to rubygems?

Comment: @wallerjake of course build the gem `gem build yourgem.gemspec`, then install it `gem install yourgem.gem`

Comment: Yeah it says it's installed but when I type my gemname mycommand it says gemname not found. Successfully installed gemname-0.0.1
Parsing documentation for gemname-0.0.1
Installing ri documentation for gemname-0.0.1
1 gem installed

Comment: Now I am getting this 
bundler: command not found: gemname
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`

Comment: @wallerjake ok, just show `bundle show gemname` => `/path/to/gemname` then `ls /path/to/gemname/bin`

Comment: Okay the command shows up when I do that? I guess was that for debugging purposes or what? Do you have a simple example Gem that I could reference?

Comment: @wallerjake no only, bundler also controls system wide gems, so you just need to determine the location of the gem, and to look into its **bin/** folder

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46263/discussion-between-wallerjake-and--)

Comment: @wallerjake has my answer been helpful?

Comment: Yes helpful in debugging. Not sure why this doesn't work though `git ls-files -- bin/*`.split("\n").map{ |f| File.basename(f) } I should probably debug it further. I think my answer on how I solved it might be the right way though at least it worked for me.

Comment: @wallerjake try to exec in console: `git ls-files -- bin/*` an provide output

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you've not commited your code yet.
Check if `git ls-files -- bin/*` shows you the script you want to execute.

When you commit your file, then `git ls-files` will return it and the spec will be able to load the script.

Comment: I think @Малъ Скрылевъ's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21373096/2661448) was pointing the same direction. Credits for him!

Comment: Yes I believe you are right. I left it for now but I intend to come back and update again. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Checkout these blog posts:
http://robdodson.me/blog/2012/06/14/how-to-write-a-command-line-ruby-gem/
http://rubylearning.com/blog/2011/01/03/how-do-i-make-a-command-line-tool-in-ruby/

I'm not really sure what you've built so far but here are a few points of interest:

1. `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` for first line in the executable file (in the `/bin` folder).
2. `chmod +x filname` to make it executable
3. `ARGV[0]` Variables passed in are retrieved from `ARGV[0]`
4. `s.executables << 'your_file'` Add executable to gemspec

Comment: Okay so it seems I can run bin/mycommand but not gemname mycommand Is that how it's suppose to work? Do I need to configure something so I can run gemname mycommand?

Comment: added the `executables` line. give that a try

Comment: This is what bundle gem gave me for that.  spec.executables   = spec.files.grep(%r{^bin/}) { |f| File.basename(f) } Is this not correct? Should I try just putting the specific file in place? Also do I need to reload the Gem doing bundle install?

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out at least for my specific issue. I just need to call out the bin command directly instead of that git ls loop. The top one works the bottom one doesn't for some reason.

`spec.executables   = ["toolshed"]`

vs

`` spec.executables   = `git ls-files -- bin/*`.split("\n").map{ |f| File.basename(f) } ``